# Configure Logrotate to only rotate partially

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, logging, logrotate

I'm using Logrotate to rotate Apache logs. But instead of starting with an empty log file after each rotation, I'd like to keep some lines from the old log.

Is there a solution which prevents the lines from being duplicated on the next rotation? Is Logrotate even the right tool for this?

Comment: "I'd like to keep some lines from the old log." It seems this is not possible.

Comment: "Is there a solution which prevents the lines from being duplicated on the next rotation?" Huh? What do you mean by this?

Comment: @DavidPostill if I copy say 10 lines into the new log, those lines would be present in file.log.1 AND file.log, effectively duplicating data unless I cut them from the old file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Logrotate rotates the entire file.

It would of course be possible to write a script that concatenates the files together and shows you the last lines of the previous log as well, a basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -5 /var/log/apache2/access.log.1
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log
```